# In multisite config, should a user with Page permissions to precisely 1 page (and not the Root page) see that page's Title in breadcrumb UI control?

Tags: wagtail

In a multisite wagtail installation, a user account is created in a Group which has permissions to precisely 1 page (which is child of Root).  When that user views the 1 page they have access to (https://my_site.org/cms/pages/52/), the "Breadcrumb" UI element which normally displays "... > PageTitle" instead displays only "...>".   When hovering on "...>", the display would normally toggle to showing "...> Root > PageTitle" but instead becomes merely "...> Root"

If I add some permissions to the user account for the 'Root' page, then this behavior goes away.  But for my use-case, I want these user accounts to be limited to actions on only a particular Site.

[image]

I would expect the breadcrumb UI to show the title of the single page that the user has access to, rather than a blank string.

I did try adding a permission on the Root page for this user, which restored the desired behavior of the breadcrumb control, but that is not a perfect solution for me.

Is it possibile that this is a bug in the wagtail admin UI page?  Or can someone suggest a workaround I can use with definitions of permissions and page hierarchy that might make this clearer for a low-privilege user account working in the CMS?  Thanks!